# Can't get category labels to display

Tags: highcharts

Trying to get category labels to display from this data:

```
{
    "chart": {
        "renderTo": "container",
        "type": "line"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Recent Sales Activity for Zipcode 78732"
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "Number of Sales"
        },
        "min": 0
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "catagories": ["Q1 2017", "Q2 2017", "Q3 2017", "Q4 2017", "Q1 2018", "Q2 2018", "Q3 2018", "Q4 2018", "Q1 2019"]
    },
    "series": [{
        "name": "Sales",
        "data": [129, 137, 115, 85, 161, 124, 102, 69, 40]
    }]
}
```

Testing with https://export.highcharts.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in `categories` property:

```
"xAxis": {
    "categories": ["Q1 2017", "Q2 2017", "Q3 2017", "Q4 2017", "Q1 2018", "Q2 2018", "Q3 2018", "Q4 2018", "Q1 2019"]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e3qb25cs/

Answer (score 0):

Replace your '**catagories**' in xAxis array with '**categories**'.

Hope it works :)